# How to bridge only IPv6 and drop all IPv4 traffic on a Linux bridge with NFT?

Tags: linux-networking, lxc, nftables

Currently, we have a network where apps on host and VMs are connected together and all VMs are behind the NAT as below

```
                ||=> Host
ISP Router => enp1s0
                |--> lxdbr0 => VM 1
                       ||====> VM 2
                       ||====> VM 3
```

**Legends:**

```
==> Passthrough connection
--> NAT connection
```

However, that approach wouldn't work for IPv6 because end-to-end connection is not possible via NAT connection. We wonder if passthrough only IPv6 is possible as below

```
                ||===IPv4===> Host
                ||             /\
                ||             ||
                ||            IPv6
                ||             ||
ISP Router => enp1s0 =IPv6=> ip6br0
                |              ||
                |             IPv6
                |              ||
                |              \/
                |---IPv4---> lxdbr0 => VM 1
                               ||====> VM 2
                               ||====> VM 3
```

The question is how to drop non-IPv6 connection with `nft` command on linux while NAT-ing IPv4? Keep in mind that [ebtables is not supported](https://lists.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-dev-public/2020-December/030231.html) anymore. So [this 7 years old Q&A post](https://serverfault.com/questions/628500/ipv4-nating-and-ipv6-bridging) won't work.

Comment: As far as I know, IPv6 is not being target of any NAT. NAT is for IPv4 only. There exist 2 kind of IPv6 addresses, global IPv6 addresses and link local IPv6 addresses. You don't need a bridge for IPv6, you just enable IPv6 on your router and your clients.

Comment: PS if you really want to "drop" IPv4, you do this with `iptables`. Just add a custom rule for your bridge interface. Keep in mind that something like this needs some CPU time.

Comment: @paladin Any idea how to do that? If yes, please answer via answer section, I appreciate that